# QGIS - How to render QgsMapCanvas on QApplication's main window

Tags: qgis, c++, visual-studio

I am working with C++, QT 5.11.3, Visual Studio 2015 and QGIS 3.7

I'm trying to develop QT c++ application that uses the qgis api. I want to display simple raster and vector map in my qt application. 
I create QgsVectorLayer and QgsRasterLayer that added to the QgsProject instance and then QgsMapCanvas object. That is no problem so far.

But when i turn the visible property of QgsMapCanvas object, the application crash. The error message and the crash window is above.

> QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread ... Reciever (of type 'QGSMapCanvas') ...

[image]

I try to this process at different qt thread or main thread no matter what, does not help.
What can i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the constructor of your main window:

```
this->setCentralWidget(canvas)
```

where `canvas` is the name of your map canvas. This will replace the central area of your main window with the canvas.